# How to call at object with callback/listener in a Worker doWork() method of the

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm am trying to use a WorkManager to schedule an API call because of my apps offline capability, but I am not sure how to handle listeners in my worker. Inside the ScenarioRunSyncHelper it builds the JsonObject and calls a WebApi class which refreshes an authentication token if required. So there are two layers of listeners. It looks like some of the other examples I have seen like [here](https://oyinloyeayodeji.medium.com/return-a-response-for-android-volley-when-using-workmanager-e030ecda4dd4) and [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics) there are no callbacks/listeners in the doWork. Their objects/methods within the doWork method throw errors so the Result.success or Result.failure can be called accordingly. Mine looks like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {


    ScenarioRunSyncHelper helper = new ScenarioRunSyncHelper();
    helper.sync(application, scenarioRun, new ScenarioRunSyncHelper.SyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    //return Result.success();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    //return Result.failure();
                }
            });

    return Result.success();
}
```

Is this accurate? Is anybody else facing this issue?

Comment: `Worker` is for synchronous work that doesn't have callbacks. Did you read the [documentation on callback based workers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker)?